# Angular cdk/drag-drop miltiple cdkDrag elements

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am working on an Angular project and I want to have columns that have elements that can be dropped in any of the columns, Also, I want to drag and drop the column itself to change the order of the columns.

[Here is moving the elements between the columns From Trello which I already have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btSvt.png)

[And here is the functionality of changing the order of the columns From Trello that I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTw4n.png)
It would be helpful if there was a way to have this functionality.

I am currently using cdk/drag-drop to move the elements between the columns but I am stuck at moving the column itself. I went through https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples and I could not find a way to have more than one type of ckdDrag elements within the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no problem, you can has an array like, e.g.

```
list = [
    { head: "to do", items: ["Get to work", "Pick up groceries", "Go home", "Fall asleep"] },
    { head: "Done", items: ["Get up", "Brush teeth", "Take a shower", "Check e-mail", "Walk dog"] }
  ];
```

An .html

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropColumns($event)">
    <div cdkDropListGroup>
        <div class="example-container" *ngFor="let items of list;let i=index" cdkDrag>
            <h2>{{items.head}}</h2>

            <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="items.items"
                class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of items.items" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See that you enclosed in `<div cdkDropListGroup>` the "columns"

And the two functions drop

```
dropColumns(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.list, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6151w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts) (if you "drag from title" you re-order the "columns")